# HTML KickStart - restore default style for input fields

Tags: html, css, html5-kickstart

The HTML KickStart framework has a nice default theme. However, I would like to restore the default style for input fields. How do I go about this by overwriting the KickStart theme?

**HTML5 Kickstart: http://www.99lime.com/**

Comment: Please define "HTML KickStart" for us.  Perhaps a link?

Comment: http://www.99lime.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `kickstart-forms.css` find CSS properties assigned for input elements and then rewrite it.

you must change :

```
input { }
input:focus { }
input[type="text"] { }
input[type="text"]:focus { }
input[type="password"] { }
input[type="password"]:focus { }
```

and every input that you don't like ;)

To restore browser default styles comment out CSS properties for input elements e.g.

```
/* This is a comment in CSS
input { }
input:focus { }
input[type="text"] { }
input[type="text"]:focus { }
input[type="password"] { }
input[type="password"]:focus { }
*/
```

or just delete aformentioned styles.

Comment: I accepted  your answer, but my question was if browser default styles can be restored anyhow.

Comment: Ok, to restore browser default styles just comment or delete CSS styles for input elements e.g. `/* input { } input:focus{ } */`

Comment: *Restore them once they have been altered

Comment: "Restore them once they have been altered" ? Do you maybe mean you want to change default styles for input fields in `HTML5 Kickstart` then if you don't like the changes you want restore `HTML5 Kickstart` default styles for input elements ?

Comment: Exactly, but not altered by me, that would be a bit silly, but by a tool such as kickstart. I know that you can simply out-commend the css you don't like, but maybe there exists a way to tell to tell the browser to set the styles for element x back to default. So, the question is: Is this possible in principle?

Comment: You mean `Kickstart` changed they styles in new version maybe and now you don't like the new styles and want to go back to old look, if that's a case then you need to download an older version of `Kickstart` if possible and use that styles.